# MySQL Join with 3 tables and empty rows

Tags: mysql, join, rows, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm giving up for now with my JOIN creating a view for search reasons - I need help :/

Here are my tables:

**Profiles**

```
id   company    user_id
1    ACME       2
2    Joe        4
3    Wolf       5
```

**Users**

```
id   role_id   online
2    4         2010-10-08
4    2         2010-10-08
5    4         2010-10-08
```

**Rubrics**

```
id    title
1     Steel
2     Stone
3     Wood
```

**Profiles_Rubrics**

```
profile_id   rubric_id
1            1
1            2
2            3
2            1
```

What I want to get from these tables is a view with one row for each profile - also including the profiles that have no entries in the HABTM Profiles_Rubrics. For now I just can get the profiles which have entries in the HABTM table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Catalog_Branches AS
SELECT
  profiles.id,
  profiles.company,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(rubrics.id AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ', ') AS rubric,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(rubrics.title AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ', ') AS rubric_title,
  profiles.user_id
FROM
  profiles,
  profiles_rubrics 
    JOIN rubrics ON profiles_rubrics.rubric_id=rubrics.id,
  users
WHERE
  profiles_rubrics.profile_id=profiles.id
  AND profiles_rubrics.rubric_id=rubrics.id
  AND users.id=profiles.user_id
  AND users.profile_online IS NOT NULL
  AND users.role_id!=1
GROUP BY
  profiles.id
```

I tried it with help from other answers here at stackoverflow but can't get to the point where it returns all profiles. I'm not a big MySQL expert as one might see from everything above :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of LEFT JOINS.

Something like

```
SELECT 
  profiles.id, 
  profiles.company, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(rubrics.id AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ', ') AS rubric, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(rubrics.title AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ', ') AS rubric_title, 
  profiles.user_id 
FROM 
  profiles LEFT JOIN
  profiles_rubrics  ON  profiles_rubrics.profile_id=profiles.id LEFT JOIN
  rubrics   ON  profiles_rubrics.rubric_id=rubrics.id LEFT JOIN
  users ON  users.id=profiles.user_id 
WHERE 
  users.profile_online IS NOT NULL 
  AND users.role_id!=1 
GROUP BY 
  profiles.id
```

Have a look at [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: +1 Astander: looks like the link to users could be an INNER JOIN without suppressing any profiles?

Comment: This is great and works as expected! Thank you very much! I didn't know that you can have concatenated (?) JOINs like you did. And trying by error is very hard with this big query :) I'm now going to apply this to another VIEW I am creating!

Comment: btw there is a typo in the WHERE clause: the first AND will fail the query - don't know if you can correct this for coming users using your answer.